# Embedded normalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, normalization

Let $S$ be an irreducible surface in a 3-dimensional variety $X$ (everything taking place over $\mathbb{C}$, say). By Hironaka's therorem, we know for sure that there is an embedded resolution of $S$, ie a morphism $X'\to X$ being a finite composition of blow-ups of smooth points and curves (with even some additional "transversality to exceptional divisors" properties), such that the strict transform $S'$ of $S$ is smooth.

What if we only want an **embedded normalization** of $S$ (ie if we ask $S'$ to be the normalization of $S$ rather than a resolution of it) ? Could we obtain that with only a finite composition of blow-ups of smooth curves in $X$ ?

(I considered contracting back some divisors from the resolved $S'\subset X'$, that had been accidentally arising through Hironaka ; since blow-ups don't commute in dimension 3, though, I can't "reduce" resolutions like $X'\to X_1\to X_2\to X$, where $X_1\to X_2$ is a point-blow-up and both other morphisms are smooth-curve-blow-ups...)

Comment: Does https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8252.pdf Proposition 3.5 answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!